# Use a Python f-string to build an SQL query 'IN' clause

Tags: python, sql, string-formatting

I'm trying to use an [f-string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions) in Python to build my SQL query.

The query below seems fine:

```
code = ('123', '234')
print(f"select * from tbl where code in {code} ")
```

Output:

> "select * from tbl where code in ('123', '234') "

However, if there is only one element in the tuple, it does not work:

```
code = ('123')
print(f"select * from tbl where code in {code} ")
```

Output:

> select * from tbl where code in 123

Why does that happen? What's the best way to solve the issue? I can use a condition to check the tuple length, but I feel like there should be a better way...

Comment: An f-string won't be able to print a single element tuple parenthesized, without a comma, so you'll need to check the length and adjust the query.

Answer (score 1):

`('123')` is not a tuple. Python interprets it simply as a string, `'123'`. In order to get a tuple with a single element you need to add a comma after the element: `('123',)`. Then the code

```
code = ('123',)
print( f"select * from tbl where code in {code} ")
```

gives:

```
select * from tbl where code in ('123',)
```

However, this is still not good since now the comma appears in the query. This can be fixed with some more formatting:

```
code = ('123',)
scode = ", ".join(f"'{s}'" for s in code)
print( f"select * from tbl where code in ({scode}) ")
```

This gives:

```
select * from tbl where code in ('123')
```

This will work for tuples of any size. For example,

```
code = ('123', '456')
scode = ", ".join(f"'{s}'" for s in code)
print( f"select * from tbl where code in ({scode}) ")
```

gives:

```
select * from tbl where code in ('123', '456')
```

If the additional comma in a tuple with a single element seems easy to miss, you can use the above code but with lists instead of tuples. So: `code = ['123']` or `code = ['123', '456']`.

Answer (score 1):

I normally do it to inject parameters and let [PyMySQL](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/), or whatever you use, inject the values.

```
code = ('123', '234')

# The below will produce a string %s,%s
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(code))

# The query will end up being:
# select * from tbl where code in(%s,%s)
sql_query = f"select * from tbl where code in({format_strings})"
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql_query, code)
```

For the second, as bb1 mentioned, it's not technically a tuple. You'll need to append a comma after the last element.

```
code = ('123',)

# The below will produce a string %s,%s
format_strings = ','.join(['%s'] * len(code))

# The query will end up being:
# select * from tbl where code in(%s)
sql_query = f"select * from tbl where code in({format_strings})"
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql_query, code)
```